# How to fix turborepo warning: failed to contact turbod

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, vite, turbo, turborepo

I'm getting this warning when I run my **Turborepo** project. My current turbo version is `1.7.0`.

I get this warning at every initial start of my app using `yarn dev`. Once the app is running I do not get any issues or warnings after that.

The warning looks like this:

### `failed to contact turbod. Continuing in standalone mode: connection to turbo daemon process failed. Please ensure the following:`

You can check the image below.

[image: Turborepo turbo daemob error]

---

I tried removing `node_modules` and caches. But nothing fixes it.

Answer (score 5):

`TEMPORARY FIX:` I fixed the issue by deleting the turbod folder under .../Temp, remove node_modules, remove npm  cache, and installing

Comment: What's the location of this Temp folder?

Comment: Its this folder you need to delete C:\users\codes\AppData\Local\Temp\turbod

Comment: It temporarily removed the warning. But It came back after some time. Seems like it generated tubod folder when I restarted the project a few times.

Answer (score 3):

Same project, I tested this on `Mac OS 13 (M1) Ventura`, and there is no daemon warning in it. Our web app is hosted on a `Linux` server and there is no daemon warning on the Linux server. It's more common on `Windows` and few `Mac` devices (based on comments).

There is an open [issue](https://github.com/vercel/turbo/issues/3455) on `turbo` as well.

But you can use `--no-daemon` while running your app to disable `daemon`. We disabled it for the local `dev` environment, but it's still enabled for production `build` because our build command will run on a `Linux` server in most cases.

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "turbo run build",
    "dev": "turbo run dev --no-daemon",
    ...
}
```

And I tried the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75247820/8730140) below provided by @Jas is a `TEMPORARY` fix. When you run turbo commands a few times, new `Temp` and `cache` files build up. It starts showing the warning again.

Comment: Unrelated but stuff like this is exactly why coding on Windows is such a nuisance despite all the rage about WSL2. - written from a windows computer. Personally I just stopped using turborepo for now

Comment: I'm getting this on MacOS tho, so this is not true.

Comment: What Mac version and chipset are you using? I have no issue on Macbook running `Mac OS 13 (Ventura)` with an `M1` chipset. But for the same project If I run on Windows 10 I get this warning. So I believe the chipset or OS plays a role here.

Answer (score 2):

**For avoiding the message in Windows, you can add this flag in your command:**

```
--no-daemon
```

Other fixes seems to be temporary. Running

```
npx turbo daemon clean
```

Worked for me but only for the next command (windows)

Comment: Running `npx turbo daemon clean` did the trick for me.